# Is the following two variable function continuous at origin?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let \begin{align}
    f(x,y) = 
        \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
            \dfrac{x^2 |x|^{\beta}y}{x^4+y^2} & \text{if} & x \ne 0 \\
            0                     & \text{if} &  x =   0
        \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

Is this function continuous for all $\beta \ > 0 $  at $ (0,0) $?

My attempt: I have tried for particular  $ \beta = 1/2$ and I think it is not continuous for that. But I am unable to proceed any hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$x^4+y^2\geq 2x^2|y|$$ so we get
$$\frac{x^2|x|^\beta|y|}{2x^2|y|}=\frac{|x|^\beta}{2}$$ and this tends to zero if $$0<\beta<1$$

Comment: But this says nothing for $\beta\geq1$.

Comment: For 
β≥1
the function 
|x
|
β
|x|β
is monotonously increasing and tends not to zero. – Dr. Sonnhard Graubner 5 hours ago   Delete